# "android" command run only with sudo on Mac OS

Tags: command-line, osx-lion, permissions, java, android

When I run `android` command I take following exception in bash, but it's everything ok with sudo.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1387)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1366)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:315)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:325)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:266)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:123)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:87)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:339)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:322)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Usually the problem is in the lack of java, but `java -version` works fine. Looks like that android have no permissions to use java, but how it could be? Same thing with Apple and Oracle Java.

P.S. MacOS 10.7.5

Comment: I'm not sure whether a [NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) can be thrown due to lack of required permissions.

Comment: I don't try to run my java program, I launch 'android' from android-sdk. I don't think that problem is in it's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why `android` command successfully run with sudo but I find a solution.

Scheme to solve this issue: (paths for MacOS 10.7.5)

1. Check that JDK installed. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
2. Open ~/.android/avd - this is a folder with avds(there was no one of .avd for me and I just removed corresponding .ini)

In this exception we can find that problem in parseAvdInfo. (In 21.0.1 sdk tools version this issue isn't solved, and `android` throws this exception. May be later the solution is in the update android sdk)